# How can I let users authenticate into my django-react website with github?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, github, django-react

I can't find ANYTHING on google or stackoverfliow about this. I'm using django and react and I want one of those "Log in with Github" buttons on my login page. I doubt anyone has time to write the whole process but maybe a link to a good source? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example that demonstrates various social Authentication [**starts with Github integration**]. I will also attach official python Social-Auth documentation.

[Integrating various Social Auth - including Github auth](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)

[Python Django Social-Auth Documentation](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html)